# how do I calculate distance between two locations

Tags: python

I used http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json to get lat and long
and saved into DB.
I am trying to write code that calculates between two locations.
is there any good api that calculates distance between two distances.
I have some locations in Asian and Europe.
Google distance only returns driving distance I want to have a actually distance.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need an API? It's a formula that you can look up with google. It's just spherical trigonometry.

Comment: You don't need an API, just the Haversine formula.

Comment: Depending on your DB - it may even have functions/indices that do this for you...

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalDistance.html

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the distances by using the Haversine formula

Here, `origin` and `destination` are lat,long tuples

```
import math

def haversine(origin, destination):

    lat1, lon1 = origin
    lat2, lon2 = destination
    radius = 6371

    dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
    a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
        * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = radius * c

    return d

c1 = [43.47066971,-80.54305153]
c2 = [43.46745,-80.54319]

print haversine(c1, c2) # 0.358189763734
```